# AppEngine Channel API - Best way to check if a channel is still open (server side)

Tags: api, sockets, google-app-engine, channel-api

I have built a social network/dating type application on the AppEngine and am currently in the process of adding a chat built on top of the Channel API. However, the problem that I have is that users may reload or navigate to new pages while the chat is going on (as they can in Facebook). This means that the server doesn't easily know if it should generate a new channel ID token for a given client, or if a given client has already been assigned a channel token.

It would be extremely useful if there were a way to check (server side) if a particular client already has a channel open. For example, if I assign a client "Jack" a channel ID of "Jack-Jan-21-2010", then I would like to be able to check on the server side if there is already a channel open associated with the ID "Jack-Jan-21-2010". This can be  (sort of) tracked on the client side by watching for an onerror() and onclose() callback, but I can't see anything server-side that allows me to just check if a channel associated with a given ID is already open.

Does anyone know an intelligent way to check (server side) if a channel has already been opened, while using the AppEngine Channel API?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Part 1: Solving your problem

See Part 2 below if you really need to track client connections, but I'm not sure from your question if what you're asking for will solve your problem.

Let me see if I can echo your problem back: you're writing a chat app, but it's for a site which isn't fully AJAX (in the way that, say, gmail is); the site contains page navigation where you may need to re-set up your channel after the user clicks on a link to another page. When the user navigates, the new page is rendered, and you want to avoid getting a new token at that point; you want to reuse the existing token and channel with the same client-id.

If that's correct, I have two alternate solutions, one easy but with not-great user experience, one trickier but with a much smoother end result.

- Preserve the token in a cookie. When you re-render your page, just use the token from the cookie instead of calling channel.create_channel again. When the token expires you'll get an onerror callback just like if the user had stayed on the original page; at this point, call channel.create_channel again. The problem with this is that re-connection can be slow (up to 10 seconds or more in bad cases) because of the nature of Comet connections.
- Wrap your entire site that's not chat-related in an iframe. Put your channel creation code and UI in the outer iframe. This way you don't have to re-connect every time the user navigates. This avoids the downtime on navigation. Note that orkut uses this technique, with floating divs, as a small amount of Firebug investigation will reveal.

## Part 2: Your feature request

If it turns out I'm misunderstanding and you really do need to track client connections:

There's not a built-in way to check if a client is connected to a channel identified by a client-id now.

However, I am working right now on adding "presence" (in the chat sense) so that your app can register to get a post when a client connects to or disconnects from a channel created with a given client id. You also might be able to "probe" presence, to query whether a given client id is connected or not (still working on the details of this part).

Note that this won't be token-based, but rather client-id based.

I don't have a definite release date for this yet but as I said I'm actively working on it right now.

In the meantime, you could use a heartbeat HTTP request from your client back to your app that says, "hey, I'm still here" every minute or so. You'll need to have some sort of task that runs every, say, 2 minutes and marks any clients that haven't checked in as inactive, and you'll need to store this data someplace.

Comment: Wow, great answer. I am going to digest it over the next few hours. Thanks and kind regards. -Alex

Comment: You have accurately echoed my problem back, and the solutions that you have proposed seem to be reasonable work arounds. I think the iframe solution looks interesting and will probably solve my problem.

Comment: Moishe, I'll buy you a delicious turkey sammich if you get that "presence" done in the next release. kthnx :)

Comment: Why the heartbeat must be in POST?

Comment: Sorry for that, it doesn't have to be a POST. Just some sort of HTTP request.

Comment: No hope for a turkey sandwich, but check out the pre-release notes for 1.5.1 :) https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/767a446a246fc6e4?pli=1

Comment: With the new API, is there a way to check if the Channel is open? ChannelPresence has an "isConnected" value. But how to get a ChannelPresence if I only have the clientId. I want to delete/reuse a token whenever the server says "Skipping message to unconnected channel: [...]."