# How to keep track of the number of active user in a Channel API chat

Tags: google-app-engine, chatroom, channel-api

I'm working on a small chat using the google Channel API and appengine. Is there an easy way to know how many users are active on the chat?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking to track how many clients are connected to a given channel, the answer should be easy: 1. The Channel API doesn't support broadcast.

If you're asking for how to track whether a client is connected to a channel, there's not a built-in way to do that right now. You can see the answer to this question for more info: [AppEngine Channel API - Best way to check if a channel is still open (server side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804129/appengine-channel-api-best-way-to-check-if-a-channel-is-still-open-server-side/4807179#4807179)

Presence for the Channel API (referenced in the above question) is coming very, very soon.